# SVELTE how to fix page flicker

Tags: javascript, svelte

In the app below I am encountering the notorious page flick effect that usually is a result of AJAX request. In my situation it is not due to AJAX it is due to a conditional that results in rendering different versions of the same page.

https://workflow-magic-svelte.vercel.app/

I have included  a gif image video so you can see the problem.

Code is below.

[image]

```
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";
  import Dexie from "dexie";
  import SearchAndCreateField from "../components/SearchAndCreateField.svelte";
  import {
    createClient,
    getAllClients,
    deleteClient,
  } from "../storageAPI/indexedDB";
  import { showNav } from "../store/nav_animation.js";
  import { animateNav } from "../store/nav_animation.js";
  import { fade, fly } from "svelte/transition";
  import { spring } from "svelte/motion";
  import BackButton from "../components/BackButton.svelte";

  //  import downloadjs from "downloadjs";

  let clients = [];
  let firstUseCookieBool;

  onMount(function () {
    firstUseCookieBool = document.cookie.split(";").some(function (item) {
      return item.trim().indexOf("workflow-magic=") == 0;
    });

    getAllClients().then((result) => {
      let list = result.reverse();
      clients = [...list];
    });
  });

  async function submitToDatabase(item) {
    try {
      let id = await createClient(item); // create new client
      // let result = await getAllClients(); // get all clients
      getAllClients().then((result) => {
        clients = [...result.reverse()]; // store new state to page
        // show nav if
        if (result.length > 1) {
          showNav.set(true);
          animateNav.set(false);
        }

        if (result.length === 1 && !firstUseCookieBool) {
          animateNav.set(true);
          document.cookie = "workflow-magic=user-first-submit-true";
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  function goToRoute(item) {
    console.log(item);

    window.location.href = "#/client/" + item.id + "/dashboard";
  }

  async function onDelete(id) {
    let clientID = clients[id].id;
    await deleteClient(clientID);
    await getAllClients().then((result) => {
      let list = result.reverse();
      clients = [...list];
      console.log(clients);
    });
  }
</script>

{#if $showNav || $animateNav}
  <div class="logo-form-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-0" />

        {#if $animateNav && !$showNav}
          <div class="col-12">
            <div
              class="background-image"
              in:fade={{ x: 0, y: 0, duration: 500 }}
            />

            <h2 class="logo-title">Workflow Magic</h2>
            <h3 class="app-is-ready-text">Your app is ready!</h3>
            <p class="get-started-text" in:fly={{ y: -50, duration: 900 }}>
              Add all the clients you want.<br /> Use the up and down arrows on
              your keyboard. <br />
              To go to the next step, select a client!
            </p>
          </div>
        {/if}

        {#if !$animateNav && $showNav}
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="background-image" />

            <h2 class="logo-title">Workflow Magic</h2>
            <h3 class="app-is-ready-text">Your app is ready!</h3>
            <p class="get-started-text">
              Add all the clients you want.<br /> Use the up and down arrows on
              your keyboard. <br />
              To go to the next step, select a client!
            </p>
          </div>
        {/if}

        <div class="col-0" />
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-0" />
        <div class="col-12">
          <SearchAndCreateField
            arrayOfObjects={clients}
            keyToRender="name"
            buttonText="Create Client"
            onSubmit={submitToDatabase}
            {onDelete}
            onSelectionEvent={goToRoute}
            placeholder="Type the name of a company or client you work with"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-0" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{:else}
  <div class="logo-form-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-0" />
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2 class="logo-title">Workflow Magic</h2>

          <h2 class="top-text">
            Workflow Magic is an organizer tool for work-from-home contractors
            and freelancers.
            <br />
            Get Started Now!
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-0" />
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-0" />
        <div class="col-12">
          <SearchAndCreateField
            buttonText="Create Client"
            placeholder="Type the name of a company or client you work with"
            arrayOfObjects={clients}
            keyToRender="name"
            onSubmit={submitToDatabase}
            {onDelete}
            onSelectionEvent={goToRoute}
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-0" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{/if}

<style>
  .get-started-text {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #787878db;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }

  .top-text {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #000db;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: logoFont;
    src: url(/fonts/next.ttf);
  }

  .logo-title {
    font-family: logoFont;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    color: #be3ebc91;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .background-image {
    background-image: url(/background_image/background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 43% 60%;
    bottom: 60px;
    top: -190px;
    width: 150%;
    left: 8px;
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.2;
  }

  .logo-form-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
  }

  .app-is-ready-text {
    color: #819dc2;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2em;
  }
</style>



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBSym.gif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pasted the code for `Landing.svelte`, but looking at the deployed site, I can see the bug is located in `App.svelte`.

In the `onMount` method of `App.svelte`, you call `getAllClients()`, which returns a Promise. After that Promise resolves, `animateNav` and `showNav` have new values assigned to them.

You should introduce a loading variable to hide all content until the async calls that you need to make fully resolve. See how I reproduced the issue and solved it [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/6928b555670a445ca4d8aced48b22def?version=3.46.2).

The page appears to flicker because of how quickly the Promise resolves—use `setTimeout` to see the flicker take longer.

Comment: Hey, I think the landing page and the app.js page have the problem. The landing.svelte page body flickers and the app.js navigation bar flickers. I didn't notice it was both. I was initially focused on the page flicker not the nav flicker - but it's both.

Comment: You should be able to use the same solution for both instances of the problem—an alternative solution I have not had time to investigate fully is using the `load` function as a way to fetch the data without needing a loading spinner. https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading

Comment: @William—did this answer your question? Please accept it if so.

Comment: It seems like the idea is right but I haven't been able to fix my code yet. Trying to figure out how to create a loading event using my code. Bear with me. I'm slow

Comment: The solution I decided on was just a basic boolen to show a blank page until the loading was done. It was a lot easier than your example but thanks for going the extra mile

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Move the function `showNav.set(true)` to inside `onMount()` (but always show the navbar);

or

2. Insert css:

   .navbar {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   }

Comment: I want to keep the nav bar hidden and your second solution does not work or make sense (maybe I don't understand). The flicker happens AFTER a user enters a client and then if they refresh the page. The video I posted shows the flicker.